# J2ee and java: i have prob with my function java he didn't work with DB (mysql)

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee

Hey my Friends I have some problem with my code he didn't work 
I think this problem in my Class UserService but I'm not sure please help me
When I run my programme 
my console affiche :

```
On train de detecter
```

UtlisateurAction.java

```
package com.web.actions;

import java.util.List;

import com.app.business.bo.security.Role;
import com.app.business.bo.security.Utlisateur;
import com.app.business.services.UtlisateurService;
import com.app.exceptions.DuplicateLoginException;
import com.web.BaseAction;

public class UtlisateurAction extends BaseAction {



    private UtlisateurService userService;

    private List<Utlisateur> listUsers;

    private Utlisateur utilisateur;

    private List<Role> listRoles;

    private Long selectedRole;


    public String passage(){
        System.out.println("Passage");
    return SUCCESS;
    }
    public String showMenu(){
        System.out.println("User Access");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String initFormAddUser() {
        listRoles = userService.getAllRoles();

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String addUser() {

        try {
            utilisateur.setRole(userService.getRoleById(selectedRole));
            userService.addUtilisateur(utilisateur);

        } catch (DuplicateLoginException ex) {
            addActionError("Operation non effectuee a  cause d'une erreur");

            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "error";

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            addActionError("Operation non effectuee Ã  cause d'une erreur");

            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "error";

        }
        // on affiche une page d'erreur
        addActionMessage("Utilisateur ajoutée avec succées");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String listUsers() {
        System.out.println("On train de detecter");
        listUsers = userService.getAllUsers();
        System.out.println("GET ALL USERS");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Utlisateur> getListUsers() {
        return listUsers;
    }

    public void setListUsers(List<Utlisateur> listUsers) {
        this.listUsers = listUsers;
    }

    public UtlisateurService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    public void setUserService(UtlisateurService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public Utlisateur getUtilisateur() {
        return utilisateur;
    }

    public void setUtilisateur(Utlisateur utilisateur) {
        this.utilisateur = utilisateur;
    }

    public List<Role> getListRoles() {
        return listRoles;
    }

    public void setListRoles(List<Role> listRoles) {
        this.listRoles = listRoles;
    }

    public Long getSelectedRole() {
        return selectedRole;
    }

    public void setSelectedRole(Long selectedRole) {
        this.selectedRole = selectedRole;
    }

}
```

my function :

```
public String listUsers() {
            System.out.println("On train de detecter");
            listUsers = userService.getAllUsers();
            System.out.println("GET ALL USERS");
            return SUCCESS;
        }
```

UtlisateurServiceImpl.java

```
package com.services.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.orm.ObjectRetrievalFailureException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import com.bo.security.Role;
import com.bo.security.Utilisateur;
import com.boudaa.dao.exceptions.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.dao.RoleDao;
import com.dao.UtilisateurDao;
import com.exceptions.DuplicateLoginException;
import com.services.UtilisateurService;

public class UtilisateurServiceImpl implements UtilisateurService, UserDetailsService {

    private UtilisateurDao userDao;
    private RoleDao roleDao;

    protected final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String pLogin) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Utilisateur lUser = null;
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> arrayAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        // On rÃ©cupÃ¨re un objet de domaine de type User ayant comme login pLogin
        try {
            lUser = userDao.getUserByLogin(pLogin);

        } catch (ObjectRetrievalFailureException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            // nous relanÃ§ons une UsernameNotFoundException si aucun utilisateur
            // ne correspond Ã  cet login
            log.debug("Erreur d'authentification avec le login : " + pLogin);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + pLogin + " not exists", ex);

        }


        // Si un utilisateur correspond Ã  cet identifiant, nous en profitons
        // pour mettre Ã  jour sa date de derniÃ¨re connexion
        lUser.setLastAccessDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        userDao.update(lUser);
        // Il faut ensuite rÃ©cupÃ©rer les rÃ´les de lâ€™utilisateur et les
        // mettre
        // sous la forme de SimpleGrantedAuthority, une interface propre Ã 
        // Spring
        // Security*

        Role role = lUser.getRole();
        arrayAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
        // /un User (classe Spring Security) est crÃ©Ã©
        System.out.println("oui");
        return new User(pLogin, lUser.getPassword(), lUser.isEnabled(), lUser.isAccountNotExpired(), true,
                lUser.isAccountNotLocked(), arrayAuths);
    }


    public Utilisateur getUserByLogin(String pLogin) throws EntityNotFoundException {

        List<Utilisateur> users;
        try {
            users = userDao.getEntityByColumn("Utilisateur", "login", pLogin);

        } catch (ObjectRetrievalFailureException ex) {

            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Aucun utilisateur avec le login : " + pLogin);
        }

        if (users.size() != 1) {
            // TODO : Ecrire le code pour ajouter des log fatal
            // TODO : ecrire le code envoyant un mail d'erreur fatal Ã 
            // l'administrateur

            throw new RuntimeException("Erreur inconnue dans le systeme");
        }

        return users.get(0);
    }
    public void addUtilisateur(Utilisateur user) throws DuplicateLoginException {

        // pour hacher avec SHA1
        ShaPasswordEncoder encoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder();


        // Hachage du mot de passe avec un gain de sel variable = login
        String cryptedPassword = encoder.encodePassword(user.getPassword(),
                user.getLogin());

        // affecter le mot de passe hachÃ©
        user.setPassword(cryptedPassword);

        // stockage de l'utilisateur dans la base de donnÃ©es
        try {
            userDao.create(user);

        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
            log.error("erreur d'ajout d'un utilisateur Ã  cause de l'exception " + ex
                    + " . un utilisateur avec le login " + user.getLogin() + " existe dÃ©jÃ  dans la base de donnÃ©es");
            throw new DuplicateLoginException("Erreur d'inscription, login existe dÃ©jÃ ", ex);
        }

    }

    public Role getRoleByName(String roleName) {
        return roleDao.getRoleByName(roleName);
    }

    public Role getRoleById(Long pRoleId) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return roleDao.findById(pRoleId);
    }

    public List<Utilisateur> getAllUsers() {
        return userDao.getAll();
    }

    public List<Role> getAllRoles() {
        return roleDao.getAll();
    }

    public void deleteUser(Utilisateur u) throws EntityNotFoundException {

        userDao.delete(u.getIdUtilisateur());

    }

    public UtilisateurDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(UtilisateurDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    public RoleDao getRoleDao() {
        return roleDao;
    }

    public void setRoleDao(RoleDao roleDao) {
        this.roleDao = roleDao;
    }


}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/services</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>root</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>azertyui</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource">

        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>

            <value>com/app/business/dao/hbm/Utlisateur.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/app/business/dao/hbm/Filiere.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/app/business/dao/hbm/Matiere.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/app/business/dao/hbm/Niveau.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/app/business/dao/hbm/Document.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/app/business/dao/hbm/Role.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
                    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
                </prop>
            </props>

        </property>


    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="defaultTxAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="loadUserByUsername" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="create*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="*" read-only="true" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="defaultServiceOperation"
            expression="execution(* com.app.business.services.Impl.*Service*.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="defaultServiceOperation"
            advice-ref="defaultTxAdvice" />
    </aop:config>

    <bean id="NiveauDao"
        class="com.app.business.dao.Impl.NiveauDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="DocumentDao"
        class="com.app.business.dao.Impl.DocumentDaoImp">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="FiliereDao"
        class="com.app.business.dao.Impl.FiliereDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="MatiereDao"
        class="com.app.business.dao.Impl.MatiereDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="DocumentService"
        class="com.app.business.services.Impl.DocumentServiceImpl">
        <property name="documentdao" ref="DocumentDao"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="UtlisateurDao"
        class="com.app.business.dao.Impl.UtlisateurDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="RoleDao" class="com.app.business.dao.Impl.RoleDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="UtlisateurService"
        class="com.app.business.services.Impl.UtlisateurServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="UtlisateurDao"></property>
        <property name="roleDao" ref="RoleDao"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="UtlisateurAction"
        class="com.web.actions.UtlisateurAction" scope="prototype">
        <property name="userService" ref="UtlisateurService"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="SecurityAction" class="com.web.actions.SecurityAction" scope="prototype">
        <property name="utilisateurService" ref="UtlisateurService"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Too much code.  You should be able to test an individual data access class.  What does "doesn't work" look like?  Is there a stack trace?

Comment: this function public String listUsers() {
            System.out.println("On train de detecter");
            listUsers = userService.getAllUsers();
            System.out.println("GET ALL USERS");
            return SUCCESS;
        }

Comment: my strack trace return On train de detecter only

Comment: No,  a stack trace would tell you what the error was and the line at which it occurred.  That output is your error message - a poor substitute.

Comment: I think my problem in function getAllUsers() but when I test this function he didn't work

Comment: No one can help you if all you tell us is "it didn't work".

Comment: The problem that the console didn't display an error

Comment: That's because your code swallowed it.  Do you understand why?

Comment: please You can explain to me better ,?

Comment: Stacktraces

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.web.actions.UtlisateurAction.listUsers(UtlisateurAction.java:67)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: I'll guess that userService is null.  Figure out why and you'll solve your problem.

Comment: yes ,I see no annotations in the code.

Comment: please You can explain to me better ,?